# Grails never redirect to login page

Tags: spring, security, grails

How to force a user to go to login page if he tries to access protected resource?
I am trying to implement ajax-based authentication. Simple logging-in and logging-out procedure seems to work fine, but whenever i try to access a resource that requires logging in all i get is an 404 error (in html body i see 403 error instead).

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a problem because i am using x509 authentication at the same time. Disabling x509 makes everything work, but i need it working together

Comment: I met the same problem. Have you got the solution?